# XElement constructror

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I found an example of using XElement where object is being created in this way:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("contacts",
                    new XElement("contact", 
                        new XAttribute("contactId", "2"),
                        new XElement("firstName", "Barry"),
                        new XElement("lastName", "Gottshall")
                    )
                );
```

But XElement constructon can be created only using an array of objects

> XElement(XName, Object[])

I don't see any array initializers in this code. How does it work?

Comment: public XElement(XName name, Object content) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341343.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content parameter of [XElement constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302741.aspx) defined as `params Object[]`:

```
public XElement(
    XName name,
    params Object[] content
)
```

which means you can pass [any number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) of any arguments here. That is exactly what happening in example you have found.

> I don't see any array initializers in this code. How does it work?

Array will be created [by compiler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/params). If you will [disassemble](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) your example, you will see

```
XElement xml = new XElement("contacts",
                    new XElement("contact", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("contactId", "2"),
                        new XElement("firstName", "Barry"),
                        new XElement("lastName", "Gottshall")
                    })
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

the answers above me solve the mystery, but i just want to mention that the `params` keyword is a powerful tool for receiving any number of arguments  from the same type to a method. It must be the last parameter on the method signature, and we use it all the time in `string.format` for example. saves a lot of time and easy to use

Comment: There's a fine line between easy and lazy depending on your needs.